# Adding COLUMNS to EXCEPTIONS table created by UTLEXCPT.SQL script

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I know that @?/rdbms/admin/utlexcpt can be used to create EXCEPTIONS table. This table is used in statement as follows :

```
ALTER TABLE my_tab enable constraint my_tab_fk1 exceptions into MY_EXCEPTIONS
```

I want to customize MY_EXCEPTIONS table by adding new columns. But then executing above script gives following error:

```
 ORA-00947: not enough values.
```

This is understandable because Oracle is expecting the MY_EXCEPTIONS table to have pre-defined structure only.

Is there a workaround so that the data failing EXCEPTIONS is captured into a table which has additional columns ?

Comment: How would Oracle know what to put into the extra columns?

Comment: if Oracle was populating only the 4 columns which are in the standard EXCEPTIONS table ( row_id, owner, table_name & constraint ), the additional columns could be populated by a trigger or by specifying a default value. But it seems it is not possible. Thanks @AlexPoole.

Comment: But with what data/values? I don't understand how this would be useful. I suppose you *could* create a view with the same columns as the standard table, and an instead-of trigger on that which populates your extended table? I'm still missing something though...

Comment: Assume a column - DATE_INSERTED with default of SYSDATE. it will be automatically populated, without breaking Oracle's native process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with a view. If your parent and child tables were something like this:

```
create table my_parent_tab (id number primary key);
create table my_tab (id number,
  fk_id number,
  constraint my_tab_fk1 foreign key (fk_id)
    references my_parent_tab (id) disable
);
```

and you created your exceptions table based on the `utlexcpt.sql` script with with an extra column:

```
create table my_exceptions(row_id rowid,
  owner varchar2(30),
  table_name varchar2(30),
  constraint varchar2(30),
  date_inserted date default sysdate -- extra column
);
```

then you could create a view over that table, for only the columns the exception handler is expecting:

```
create view my_exceptions_view as
select row_id, owner, table_name, constraint
from my_exceptions;
```

with an instead-of trigger that populates the table, either supplying an explicit value or replying on the default for the extra column:

```
create trigger my_exception_trigger
instead of insert on my_exceptions_view
for each row
begin
  insert into my_exceptions (row_id, owner, table_name, constraint)
  values (:new.row_id, :new.owner, :new.table_name, :new.constraint);
end;
/
```

Then while the constraint is disabled add data including some that isn't valid:

```
insert into my_parent_tab (id) values (1);
insert into my_tab (id, fk_id) values (1, 1);
insert into my_tab (id, fk_id) values (2, 2);
```

Then you can enable the constraint and point to the view instead of the table:

```
alter table my_tab enable constraint my_tab_fk1
  exceptions into my_exceptions_view; -- use view not underlying table

ORA-02298: cannot validate (MY_SCHEMA.MY_TAB_FK1) - parent keys not found
02298. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - parent keys not found"
*Cause:    an alter table validating constraint failed because the table has
           child records.
*Action:   Obvious
```

and the exception table shows the information, including the extra column:

```
select * from my_exceptions;

ROW_ID             OWNER                          TABLE_NAME                     CONSTRAINT                     DATE_INSERTED      
------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ -------------------
AABiK8AAEAAAAAzAAB MY_SCHEMA                      MY_TAB                         MY_TAB_FK1                     2017-08-25 20:20:14
```

Comment: Good job Alex. This answer is going the extra mile.